# Table of records with multiple csrf_field() on DELETE

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i been learning laravel, but i have some questions, most of the online  classes teach us most of the same way a subject that is in the Delete method on a list of records from the database, basically wrap up a form on a delete button, and then isnert the  `{{csrf_field()}}` inside, the only issue i found is that if i loop all my records, it will have multiple forms with  `{{csrf_field()}}` it doesnt feel very elegant. Is there another way in deleting records without making so dirty?

Comment: What makes it feel so `dirty` to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, for example, create one general `DELETE` form, in which you set the record ID dynamically, using jQuery.

**Form**

```
<form action="some/action" method="post" id="delete-form">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="record_id">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[data-delete-id]').click(function() {
  var recordId = $(this).data('delete-id');
  $('#delete-form').find('[name=record_id]').val(recordId);
  $('#delete-form').submit();
});
```

**Buttons**

```
<button data-delete-id="1">Delete record 1</button>
<button data-delete-id="2">Delete record 2</button>
```

Although nothing is wrong with your current approach, this may point you in the right direction of optimizing your code.

Another solution would be AJAX, when you don't even need a physical form, you can just build a request.